# Add a class to a image for a specific view

Tags: views, 8

I need add a class to a image for one specific views.
I tried:

- `theme_preprocess_field()` but it doesn't work
- `theme_preprocess_image()` but it's for all the images
- I tried what suggested in [Override image template for field](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/192473/override-image-template-for-field) image_formatter own, but it is too complex to simply add a CSS class
- [This answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/267279/24034) is the more accepted but I like other ways

Is it possible to override a field/image template file for a specific view?

Answer (score 2):

If your view is outputting fields (& not a teaser) you can easily do it in the views UI.

1. Edit your view
2. Click on the image field
3. STYLE SETTINGS > Customize field HTML > Create a CSS class
4. Save

Now your image field should have a class:

[image]

Comment: Just posted the same answer at the same time! (removed my one, it's ok)

Comment: Great minds think alike, I guess, @DavidThomas

Comment: @100pic This option add the class to container of field not to the img tag.